# How can I read email (gmail account) in R

Tags: r, gmail

I would like to read email received on my google account.

I've tried ‘mRpostman’ package, setting a third party psw for the purpose, as it follows:

> install.packages("mRpostman")
> library(mRpostman)
>
> con <- configure_imap(url="imaps://imap.gmail.com",
> username="xxx@gmail.com",
> password="***")
>
> con$list_mail_folders()

then I get this error:

> Error in list_mail_folders_int(self, retries) :
> Request error: the server returned an error.

Is there a specific setting for gmail that has to be set? I don't find any indication on the documentation page (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mRpostman/mRpostman.pdf), that has been updated on October 27, 2022, so I guess the package is still actively maintained.

Eventually does anyone know another package that I could use for this purpose?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you considered the gmail api?

Comment: For Gmail you will need OAuth2.0 authentication. Please, take a look at this vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mRpostman/vignettes/xoauth2.0.html I provide a very detailed step-by-step explanation of how to configure the access to Gmail accounts there.